# Ubuntu 12.10 - set alternating row colors in gtk3 TreeView

Tags: application-development, python, gtk3

Ubuntu used to have alternating row colors for gtk TreeView widgets. Some applications still do, like Banshee. Alternating row colors would really help my application (written in python 2.7, and using gi.repository and not pygtk) that I'm developing.

I know I can set a hint with

```
treeview.set_rules_hint(True)
```

This isn't working, however. Does anyone know how to enable the alternating row colors?

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not `set_rules_hint(True)` will display alternating row colors is up to the theme. With Ubuntu's default, Ambience, there will not be alternating rows. As the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.8/GtkTreeView.html#gtk-tree-view-set-rules-hint) states:

> Do not use it just because you prefer the appearance of the ruled
>   tree; that's a question for the theme. Some themes will draw tree rows
>   in alternating colors even when rules are turned off, and users who
>   prefer that appearance all the time can choose those themes. You
>   should call this function only as a semantic hint to the theme engine
>   that your tree makes alternating colors useful from a functional
>   standpoint (since it has lots of columns, generally).

That said, you can force it if your really want. For instance, this will work in Ambience:

```
view.set_rules_hint(True)
style_context = self.get_style_context()
css_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
css = """
    GtkTreeView row:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: shade(@base_color, 0.9);
    }

    GtkTreeView row:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: shade(@base_color, 1.0);
    }
    """
css_provider.load_from_data(css.encode('UTF-8'))
screen = Gdk.Screen.get_default()
style_context.add_provider_for_screen(screen, css_provider,
                                  Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)
```

Though you need to be aware that it might break in other themes. Some themes will use `@theme_base_color` instead of `@base_color` You can of course hard code the color, but who knows how that will look with the user's theme...